# deleting first element of a list.h list

Tags: c, list, linux-kernel

(I'm implementing a queue called msgQueue using linux/list.h)

```
typedef struct msgQueue
{
    long len;
    void *data;
    struct list_head queue;
} msgQueue
```

There are plenty of examples of iterating over a list and deleting the nodes like so:

```
struct list_head *pos, *q;
struct msgQueue *currentQueue;

list_for_each_safe(pos, q, &(myQueue->queue))
{
    currentQueue = list_entry(pos, struct msgQueue, queue);
    list_del(pos);
    free(currentQueue);
}
```

What is a safe way to delete just the first one?

I would've thought it would be:

```
list_del(*(myQueue->queue));
```

but that's giving me problems. (kernel paging request error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myQueue->queue` is the head of the list, so `myQueue->queue->next` is the first entry.

Given that "myQueue->queue" is a "struct list_head" (per comments):

```
if (!list_empty(myQueue->queue))
    list_del(myQueue->queue.next);
```

seems like it would delete the first entry.

I used `locate linux/list.h` and looked at the macro definitions of the for_each functions.

```
#define list_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
        pos = n, n = pos->next)
```

So in the first iteration of your loop, "pos" is `(head)->next` and `head` is `&msgQueue->queue`.

Comment: Would that make `myQueue->queue` invariably a head with no data?  just pointers to the first (next) and last (prev) entries?

Comment: No, it sutures-out the node from the list (updates entry->next->prev and entry->prev->next) and then resets the node's own prev/next values to LIST_POSION1 and LIST_POISON2. It doesn't actually delete/free the node, just unlinks it from the list.

Comment: When I try this I get compiler error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct list_head')

Comment: I'm basing this off the sample of list_for_each_safe you posted. Whatever you would pass as "head" in the macro should transplant into `list_del((head)->next)` to match your example of `list_del(pos)`. That error suggests you need to change it to `list_del(myQueue->queue.next);` and that you would actually need to call `list_For_each_safe(pos, q, &myQueue->queue);`?

Comment: I screwed that up in the question, thank you.  it is supposed to be `&myQueue->queue`

Comment: Ha - easy enough to do :) I updated the answer too :)

Comment: yep this solved a problem i've been working on forever.  I used myQueue->queue.next, btw, as you suggested.  Thank you